# stuck in an edit method with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm stuck in an easy edit method and can't go on until I solve it.

I have a list of items in the index view, each item has a view item button, a delete button, and an edit button.

I have no problem with create, show and delete, but I'm stuck with te edit method.

this is my activities_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    if @activity.update(activity_params)
        redirect_to @activity
    else
        redirect_to :edit
    end
end

private

    def activity_params
        params.require(:activity).permit(:name, :description)
    end
```

and this is the edit view:

```
<%= form_for(@activity) do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= f.text_area :description" %>
        <%= f.label :description, "Descripction" %>
    </p>
<p>
    <%= f.submit "save", class: "btn" %>
</p>
```

In the list of items view:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= activity.name %>
    <%= link_to "edit", edit_activity_path(activity), class: "btn"%>
<% end %>
```

In all the examples I followed they do the edit button in the show item view, so they use @activity as a path param, but in my loop I can't use @activity and I use `activity`. I think here is my noob fail but I can't figure how to fix it.

So when I enter to for example localhost:3000/activities/11/edit it shows me the message "param is missing or the value is empty: activity".

As I said before I think it is because I am passing as a path param activity instead of @activity and then it has not the structure I did for the strong param "activity_params". But at this moment I don't see the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the instance variable,  using `activity` as opposed to `@activity` is fine.  The problem is that the `edit` action is used to show the form, you have it confused with the `update` action, which would be used to actually update the model.

```
def edit
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    if @activity.update(activity_params)
        redirect_to @activity
    else
        render :edit
    end
end
```

is closer to what you are probably intending/trying to do.

Comment: Ah, beat me to it! :)  I'll delete my answer.